# Strange layout problem in IE caused by a hyperlink

Tags: internet-explorer, wordpress, hyperlink, youtube

I am developing a site for a client and everything was fine and dandy until I suddenly discovered a strange layout error in Internet Explorer.

You can see the test site here: [Eventplanners](http://inlusiondesign.dk/eventplanners)

Under the header slideshow and youtube video there is only suppose to be four images. If you see the site in any other browser than IE you'll see what I'm refering to.

I have narrowed the problem down to the hyperlink I am using to display the video, since the extra image block goes away if I remove the `<a>`.

I have tried using another way to embed the youtube link, but I can't get it to work with the custom thumbnail image.

The site is supposed to be done tomorrow, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I hope its just some stupid think I've overlooked, but I've spend a lot of time trying different things now, and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: can you show your html code? I know it looks good in FF and Chrome and bad in IE but I think it is because you have not closed an element properly. In IE `div#home-button` and `<h6>` are nested inside the anchor. Something is wrong there.

Comment: I had forgot to close the hyperlink. For some reason none of the other browsers reacted to it, so I had completely overlooked it. I knew it was some stupid obvious thing, but I just couldn't see it. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some relevant code errors: [[Invalid]Markup Validation of  inlusiondesign.dk eventplanners  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//inlusiondesign.dk/eventplanners/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help songdogtech! I thought I had closed the hyperlink, but apparently i hadn't - embarrassing. But it's all good now.